# Is there a way to perform a search in such a way as to exclude a specific tag?

Tags: support, tags, search

I would like to perform a search for questions tagged [java](/questions/tagged/java) but not tagged [android](/questions/tagged/android) as an example.  So in the Search dialog I would like to type `java -android search criteria`  this would search all questions tagged [java](/questions/tagged/java) and not tagged [android](/questions/tagged/android).  Make sense?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can already do this, in a manner very similar to what you described. Just be sure to wrap tags in square brackets, and prepend a `-` to those you wish to exclude.

For example, a [search for `[java] -[android] swing`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+-%5Bandroid%5D+swing) gives you search results for

[image: posts containing swing tagged with java, but not android]