# Search for one tag and exclude results for another tag

Tags: support, tags, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to perform a search in such a way as to exclude a specific tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102372/is-there-a-way-to-perform-a-search-in-such-a-way-as-to-exclude-a-specific-tag)

Is there a way to search for a tag (lets take [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)) but exclude questions tagged with, for example [forms](/questions/tagged/forms)?

So I can get all [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) question which aren't also tagged with [forms](/questions/tagged/forms)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write in search box `[c#] -[forms]`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+-forms