# Can't search multiple tags but exclude a specific tag

Tags: support, tags, search, filtering, tag-search

Currently there are two questions saying that you can do what I want:

- [Is there a way to perform a search in such a way as to exclude a specific tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102372)
- [Search for one tag and exclude results for another tag [duplicate]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/150231)

This works fine when I use [`-[python] [python-3.x]`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x+-python). However when wanting to get most Python tags except ones tagged `[python]`, it doesn't work. Doing `-[python] [python-*]` expands to `[python-3.x] or [python-2.7] or [python-2.6] -[python]`, [which contains questions tagged `[python]`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x+or+python-2.7+or+python-2.6+-python).

How can I search for all questions tagged; `[python-2.6]`, `[python-2.7]`, or `[python-3.x]`, where *none* of the questions contain `[python]`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it using parentheses with spaces around wildcarded tag. E.g.:

- [`( [python-*] ) -[python]`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=%28%20%5Bpython-*%5D%20%29%20-%5Bpython%5D)

Answer (score 3):

With the addition of [custom-filters](/questions/tagged/custom-filters) there is another way to be able to do this.

Going in the [custom filter page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=Newest&edited=true) and filter by the following tags: `not python and python-3.x or not python and python-2.x`. This will create [this filter](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/-python%20and%20python-3.x%20or%20-python%20and%20python-2.x?sort=Newest&edited=true).

---

[Credit goes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330349#comment1077740_330349) to @[Laurel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/323179/laurel).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind that results can be stale for up to 7 days, you can leverage [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

I have created this [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/701680?include=python-&exclude=python) that let you include tags (wildcard) and exclude a tag.

```sql
select distinct top 100 
       p.id as [Post Link]
     , creationdate
from posts p
inner join posttags pt on pt.postid = p.id
inner join tags t on t.id = pt.tagid
and t.tagname like ##include:string## + '%'
and p.tags not like '%<' + ##exclude:string##  + '>%'
order by p.creationdate desc
```

When you run this today this will be your result:

[image: python questions]

Keep in mind SEDE is only update once a week, on Sunday. If you want to try and create your own queries you might want to check the [awesome tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial).