# Support selecting multiple tags, except one in custom filter

Tags: feature-request, custom-filters

<sub>Posted as a separate question as [per request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330326#comment1077736_330338).</sub>

Please can you add support for saving the filter [`( [python-*] ) -[python]`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=%28%20%5Bpython-*%5D%20%29%20-%5Bpython%5D).

It's a fairly strange filter, as it gets all `[python-*]` tags except ones tagged with `[python]`. It is very useful on Code Review as ~30%, when I checked, were improperly tagged and this makes it easy to find and fix them.

Comment: It is inconvenient, especially the more tags are captured by the wildcard, but it **is** currently possible: [see here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/-python%20and%20python-3.x%20or%20-python%20and%20python-2.x?sort=Newest&edited=true)

Comment: @Laurel Oooh, nice! I didn't think to try that as the same approach didn't work with the old search method, IIRC.

Comment: I agree with this. I can't seem to even do a normal non-wildcard `([x] or [y]) and not [z]`

Comment: @Laurel That's a nice workaround, and yes, that would get cumbersome the moment python-4 is released.